# Why is Pinned state of a tab in Google Chrome returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to check if a tab status is pinned.

This is my background page:

```
<html>
  <script>

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            alert(tab.pinned);

    });

});


  </script>
</html>
```

My manifest page has an entry requesting tab permissions.

The [Tab API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) mentions:

> pinned ( boolean ) Whether the tab is pinned.

So then why is `alert(tab.pinned);` displaying an alert with `undefined` rather than true/false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce this problem. Maybe you have some very outdated Chrome? Dump returned `tab` into the console and check what properties it contains.

Also there is no need in calling `chrome.tabs.getSelected` as `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` already contains the tab you need:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log(tab);
});
```

And going forward `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`  will be called twice during the page load and once during the tab pinning/unpinning. So that's something you probably would want to take into the account.

Comment: Thanks, @Serg. Chrome version I was testing was indeed v8, I'll be trying this on Chrome 12 soon. Also, thanks for pointing out about getSelected. As for calling twice, yep, I've seen a prior SO question about that, will take care about it!

Comment: @Sathya I would advise you against Chrome 12. I had to rollback to 11 (beta branch) for the first time as 12 is simply broken right now (maybe they fixed it already not sure).

Comment: Fair enough, @Serg I'll check it out. Thanks again!